# Select multiple text options without dropdown using antd

Tags: reactjs, typescript, button, frontend, antd

**Is it possible to get the same buttons from the image and have multiple options to select**

[image]

```
import { Radio } from 'antd';
import React from 'react';

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <>
<Radio.Group defaultValue="a" style={{ marginTop: 16 }}>
      <Radio.Button value="a">Hangzhou</Radio.Button>
      <Radio.Button value="b">Shanghai</Radio.Button>
      <Radio.Button value="c">Beijing</Radio.Button>
      <Radio.Button value="d">Chengdu</Radio.Button>
    </Radio.Group>
</>
);

export default App;
```

This is the code of the buttons that I want, please can anyone tell how do I insert <Select.Option> inside this so that I can select multiple buttons at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Please to use the `Checkbox.Group` .

If you don't want to use it, you need to implement it by yourself and to use only it's styles.

This is my implements:
https://codepen.io/diqye/pen/RwJNMeE?editors=0010

```
const App = () => {
  let [seleted,setSeleted] = React.useState([])
  function btnClik(a){
    setSeleted(xs=>{
      if(xs.find(x=>x==a)){
        return xs.filter(x=>x!=a)
      }else{
        return xs.concat([a])
      }
    })
  }
  function isCheck(a){
    return seleted.find(a1=>a1==a) != null
  }
  return <>
      <Radio.Button onClick={()=>btnClik("a")} checked={isCheck("a")}>Hangzhou</Radio.Button>
      <Radio.Button onClick={()=>btnClik("b")} checked={isCheck("b")}>Shanghai</Radio.Button>
      <Radio.Button onClick={()=>btnClik("c")} checked={isCheck("c")}>Beijing</Radio.Button>
      <Radio.Button onClick={()=>btnClik("d")} checked={isCheck("d")}>Chengdu</Radio.Button>

  </>
}
```

Comment: There's no code

Comment: Also, I don't want checkbox, you can refer to the image. I want multi select text buttons.

Comment: @AnishaChoudhury wait me for a while

Comment: Im getting an error: Overload 1 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error.
      Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    Overload 2 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray<never>[]): never[]', gave the following error.
      Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.
at line no.11 in my vs code. Can you please check

Comment: That's all right in Javascript, your error got was  in Typescript ,you can type `any` like as useState<any>([]) to fix it on every error pleace